# Lambda NodeJS error: libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, lambda, couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

I get the error `libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` in my lambda when it tries to initalize

Running on Lambda using Couchbase and the Node SDK with external C bindings

---

These are the steps I do to package everything up:

1. Install libcouchbase rpm package in docker container
2. Copy across `libcouchbase.so`, `libcouchbase.so.2` and `libcouchbase.so.2.0.65` files into deployment package
3. Install couchbase npm package pointing to the `.so` files.
4. Use serverless framework to package and deploy to lambda

---

Here is a snippet of the commands I run to do so:

```
WORKDIR /lambda

RUN wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-release/couchbase-release-1.0-6-x86_64.rpm
RUN rpm -iv couchbase-release-1.0-6-x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y libcouchbase-devel libcouchbase2-bin

RUN mkdir -p libs\
  && cp /usr/lib64/libcouchbase.so libs \
  && cp /usr/lib64/libcouchbase.so.2 libs \
  && cp /usr/lib64/libcouchbase.so.2.0.65 libs

RUN npm install couchbase --compile --couchbase-root=libs
```

The error I get is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "libcouchbase.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
    "bindings (/var/task/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:213:36)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Lambda has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to `/var/task/lib` where I was putting the libraries in `/var/task/libs`